# zip in UNIX and Windows

Tags: shell, unix

Hi all I have to zip all files in a directory in UNIX and then FTP it to uniz

I have tried

```
tar -cvf abc.tar.gz folder

zip abc.tar.gz folder
```

but these files are not readable after ftp

I copied these files to local by simple FTP but windows giving error that "File is corrupted"

Please help

Comment: Did you try unzipping at the other end?

Comment: ya I did, but not worked on either side

Comment: What was the command you used to extract? And how did you do the ftp transfer? You need to give all the information needed to reproduce the problem if you want a useful answer.

Comment: unzip I dont remember it for tar files

Comment: If the file is corrupted you probably didn't use binary mode for the file transer. After opening ftp from command line, type `binary` before transferring. Does that help? Can you extract locally (using `tar -xvf abc.tar.gz`, or is it corrupted before sending. If you send it back, then do a `diff` - did the file change? All good debugging steps...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you might be using your ftp client's ASCII mode to send your archives. Make sure to use binary mode.

In ASCII mode, your binary files will get corrupted as, for example, newlines are converted.

FTP servers are usually set on binary/auto mode by default, maybe this one is set on ASCII mode instead.

Comment: It depends. What FTP client did you use?

Comment: Use command line ftp from UNIX, and after opening the connection, type `binary` before you do a `put`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the "-z" option to zip (gzip) the tar. Something like this:

```
tar -cvzf abc.tar.gz folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do two things to get your content compressed and transferred correctly:

1. add 'z' along with -cvf to enable gzip compression

   ```
   tar -cvfz abc.tar.gz folder
   ```
2. Once you are connected to the FTP host, type `binary` in the prompt to change your charset mode to binary from ASCII before you type your `put` command.

   ```
   ftp>binary
   ftp>put abc.tar.gz
   ```